# I get the Error TF400813 when I open a URL from a button

Tags: javascript, html, tfs, widget

So I coded a dashboard widget for our Team Foundation Server 2015 which works fine, expect one feature. Its a button which opens the course of a commit. So the button is like this:

```
<button onclick="openURL()">Open course</button>
```

and the openURL() function which is called:

```
function openURL() {
    var win = window.open(urlString, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Pretty simple stuff... But when i open the new Tab with the Button I get the Error:

[image]

and this

[image]

I don't know, I'm still logged in on this site and when I use the same URL and open a Tab manually it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Do you use TFS 15 or TFS 2015? You may use Fiddler to check when would you get this error.

Comment: I use TFS "15" RC2. I already debugged it with the Browser Developer Tools. It says also:
X-TFS-ServiceError: "TF400813%3a+Resource+not+available+for+anonymous+access.+Client+authentication+required."

Comment: Can you share the entire code? It is hard to check the issue with the information you provided.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I can't because it would go under company secrets. But as I said its really nothing special. If you would just code a widget with a button with this functionality it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is TFS installed on your own server or are you using the microsoft one?
In the first case try giving the permissions to the user for the repository folder on the server.

Comment: Its on our own server. May be I getting something wrong here, but when I open this URL normally I don't have the problem. And I'm admin there so is there a difference?